# How to get only recalculated cells from a google spreadsheet via Google spreadsheet API (gdata)

Tags: java, gdata, google-sheets-api

Gdata offers a way to get only changed cells from a google spreadsheet, based on a time stamp. 
How should I create the time stamp for the Gdata call?

i.e. "Only entries with a published time equal to or later than the specified timestamp will be returned." setPublishedMax() https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/Query#setPublishedMax(com.google.gdata.data.DateTime)

Is there are a way to pull the current time from the server? If I create a local time stamp, how can I sync it, what time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible, it produces:

com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: OK This service does not support the updated-min

issue is here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1388