# Spreadsheet api cell feed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to find a way to have information of cells that have been updated in a spreadsheet. Based on the spreadsheet cell feed documentation (V3) and Oauth 2.0 with the javascript client library i got all the spreadsheet information in a json format. As you can see in the image attached (where there is a screenshot of the chrome console) there is a problem. When i update ONLY a specific cell in the spreadsheet it seems that the updated field of each cell of the spreadsheet is updated with the last modified date. This is wrong. Anyone have notice that?Someone can tell me if i can solve this problem in another way?

Thank you[image]

Comment: I suspect the feature does not exist. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079715/how-to-get-only-recalculated-cells-from-a-google-spreadsheet-via-google-spreadsh But if you find a solution, I would be very interested.