# Receive real time updates from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to setup a two-way sync with a Google Spreadsheet. I can push changes in my dataset to a Google Spreadsheet using its [Google Sheets API V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/)

Now, I'd like to be able to get updates from the Google spreadsheet whenever someone make edits or adds new row in real-time or near-real-time.

Any help that points me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this manually by going to Tools-> Notification rules..

[image]

If the file is in Google Drive, you can try and make use of [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push):
To use push notifications, you need to do three things:

> Register the domain of your receiving URL. For example, if you plan to
>   use `//mydomain.com/notifications` as your receiving URL, you need to
>   register `//mydomain.com`. Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook"
>   callback receiver. This is an HTTPS server that handles the API
>   notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes. Set
>   up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to
>   watch. A channel specifies routing information for notification
>   messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL
>   where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource
>   changes, the Drive API sends a notification message as a POST request
>   to that URL.

Google walkthrough [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3g_oT03nmQ).

You can also make use of Appscript. This simple hack is from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044661/get-details-of-cells-changed-from-a-google-spreadsheet-change-notification-in-a):

```
var sheet = **whatever**;//The spreadsheet where you will be making changes
var range = **whatever**;//The range that you will be checking for changes
var compSheet = **whatever**;//The sheet that you will compare with for changes
function checkMatch(){
  var myCurrent = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  var myComparison = compSheet.getRange(range).getvalues();
  if(myCurrent == myComparison){//Checks to see if there are any differences
    for(i=0;i<compSheet.length;++i){ //Since getValues returns a 'multi-dimensional' array, 2 for loops are used to compare each element
     for(j=0;j<compSheet[i].length;++i){
      if(myCurrent[i][j] != myComparison[i][j]){//Determines if there is a difference;
       //***Whatever you want to do with the differences, put them here***
     }
    }

    myEmailer(sheet.getUrl());//Passes the url of sheet to youur emailer function 
    compSheet.getRange(range).setValues(myCurrent);//Updates compSheet so that next time is can check for the next series of changes
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to create channel for a particular file?

Comment: @KetavChotaliya, it is in the docs under "Example - Start watching for changes to a single File resource": https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#making-watch-requests