# Can we use and manipulate mysql data with google spreadsheet vice versa in php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-sheets-api

I want to use google spreadsheet on my laravel website and i want to connect mysql data with this spreadsheet. and also i want to display spreadsheet in my website page and if user will update anything in spreadsheet then it will reflect in mysql and also if data will update in mysql table then also spreadsheet data will be change. So can you please suggest me is it possible or not? and if possible then explain me with best steps.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course this is a question for someone experienced in google spreadsheet. However you can start your research independently. Everything you ask is under your control, except for google spreadsheet. So you need to research google APIs. For example, regarding spreadsheet update question you need to check if google APIs handle spreadsheet change events, so you can get some alert. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748534/receive-real-time-updates-from-a-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: I have not idea about it so can you please check it and tell me is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

By using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to fetch data you can sync you SQL data with that with any programming language that supports HTTP calls, with an easier time to [those where Google provides a client](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/libraries).

You could also use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to create a [`onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) that pushes the changed data to the MySQL table. This is by far the most elegant solution since you are not doing a full refresh every time, just grabbing the changes and pushing them over. Of course, this also requires you to have a receiving mechanism that is reachable by Apps Script, like a web-service.

Also, if you want to use data in tabular form (SQL) in your website, why not just do it all thru Google Sheets, without the SQL layer? You can use JavaScript to filter your data straight from the sheets. While it has some performance draw, it's most likely unnoticeable for the common user. And the performance difference should not appear unless you have a good SQL server setup.