# How to detect a change in a Google Sheets

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm currently using the Google Spreadsheets API to read a spreadsheet. It works fine, I read and write through it and the changes are immediately reflected in the Google spreadsheet. However I want changes I make through the web browser to be reflected in my app as well.
I can't see any events in the API, can't find any way to do it in Google either.

The spreadsheet is relatively large (1500+ rows), so I can't constantly check every single cell for a change.

Comment: Not possible via gdata style google-spreadsheet-api, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079715/how-to-get-only-recalculated-cells-from-a-google-spreadsheet-via-google-spreadsh  ... email notification looks possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044661/get-details-of-cells-changed-from-a-google-spreadsheet-change-notification-in-a ALSO, not sure about google-apps-script, maybe they added this in, is a while since I used it.

Comment: yeah, it is very annoying, they allow you to do "pull" via the API, but they limit the number of pulls per 100 seconds, which makes it useless for any kind of real-time system.  I am looking for a solution as well.  I've subscribed to your question, so please post, if you find a solution, and I will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful. Drive api provides a watch function. I have not yet tested it.
Link: [drive api watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).